# chart js pie chart : error in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I am trying to test pie chart using chart.js . I get 'cannot read property of 'length' and 'initialize' in chart.js file. I tried all options and cant find the where the problem is.

code in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/n8ox2fqb/1/

[image]

pieChart.js file has following code.

```
var   pieData = [
   {
      value: '25',
      label: 'Java',
      color: '#811BD6'
   },
   {
      value: '10',
      label: 'Scala',
      color: '#9CBABA'
   },
   {
      value: '30',
      label: 'PHP',
      color: '#D18177'
   },
   {
      value : '35',
      label: 'HTML',
      color: '#6AE128'
   }
]



var pieOptions = {};

$(document).ready(function() { 

    var ctxt = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxt,{
        type: 'pie',
        data: pieData,
        options: pieOptions
    });

});
```

Html code

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="src/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/Chart.js"></script>
    </head>
            <Title>
                Test Pie Chart
            </Title>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                 <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="pieChart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fiddle is missing some references

Comment: like what information, guide me pls.

Comment: jquery and chart.js are not added. But also I think you need the 2d context of the canvas working with chart.js.

Comment: In a fiddle you need to include libraries as external resources (over on the left). JsFiddle doesnt automatcially have chart.js and jquery included.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n8ox2fqb/9/ added external resources

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n8ox2fqb/11/  using jquery 2.2.4 and Chart.js 2.1.6

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head I am going to say there is one obvious problem to me and that is the line

```
var ctxt = document.getElementById('myChart');
```

You want

```
var ctxt = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
```

You may also be feeding the chart data in the wrong format. The 'data' property in your chart config object has a property called 'datasets' which is an array of objects. [Check out their docs here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/pie.html)